# Adding one hour to UTC_TIMESTAMP for submission to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, utc

I am using the following code to submit the UTC_TIMESTAMP to a MySQL database:

```
$logq = "INSERT INTO logs (Name, Page, Date) VALUES ('$user', '$page', UTC_TIMESTAMP())";
```

I am in the UK and the time is currently one hour ahead of the UTC_TIMESTAMP, so I would like to add one hour to the values entered, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I tried a couple of suggestions found on Stack Overflow, but both don't work.  Could someone let me know how to do this correctly?  Also, I am not sure how to handle daylight saving time.  Is there a way of accounting for this automatically?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works fine.  Do you know how UTC handles daylight saving time in the UK?

Answer (score 2):

The mysql datatype TIMESTAMP is always UTC no matter where are. You have a function FROM_UNIXTIME which converts timestamp internally into standard YYYY-MM-DD HH:SS format. When using the function FROM_UNIXTIME it will convert that UTC to your local timezone automatically. So you won't need to adjust times and accounting will always be good no matter your daylight status.

Answer (score 0):

After you created a connection to the database in PHP, query this code before any query:

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+3:00'");
```

I did not tried it but it should do the trick.

Some links about this:

- [MySQL set timezone per connection](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-set-timezone-per-connection/)
- [How to Synchronize PHP MySQL timezone Configuration](http://www.sitepoint.com/synchronize-php-mysql-timezone-configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

Please use ADDDATE function of mysql, using this you can add Hour/Month/Day in any date.

```
 ADDDATE( UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Please look the url  given below belongs to mysql date time function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This also works 
SELECT DATE_ADD( UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)